# Will the limit exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\sin([x]+x)}{[x]+x} &\textrm{if } x \neq 0, \\ 1 &\textrm{if } x = 0, \end{cases}$$

where [.] is the greatest integer function, then does
$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ exist or not?

---

I thought of using the property that  $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin g(x)}{g(x)}=1$ by which I thought that the limit should exist but my book said otherwise. What did I miss? Is there anything else that should be applied?

Comment: This could be confusing, since $[x]$ is sometimes used to mean rounding towards $0$ (especially in computer science, where this is a common behaviour of standard functions), one reason that I prefer $\lfloor x\rfloor$ instead. This might lead to the impression that $[x]=0$ for $x\approx0$, but that is not correct when $x<0$. Thus the right-sided limit is $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sin(0+x)}{0+x}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$, but the left-sided limit is $\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\frac{\sin(-1+x)}{-1+x}=\frac{\sin(-1)}{-1}=\sin1<1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left and right limits at $0$ must be equal to $1$ for continuity. But you can see that as $x\to 0^-$, $$\frac{\sin([x] +x)}{[x] + x}= \frac{\sin(-1+x)}{-1+x} \to \sin 1 \ne 1 $$

Answer (score 4):

What you missed was the fact that the function $x\mapsto\lfloor x\rfloor+x$ is discontinuous.

Not, that, if $x\in(-1,0)$, $\lfloor x\rfloor+x=x-1$ and that therefore$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\sin(\lfloor x\rfloor+x)}{\lfloor x\rfloor+x}=\frac{\sin(-1)}{-1}=\sin(1).$$But$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sin(\lfloor x\rfloor+x)}{\lfloor x\rfloor+x}=1\ne\sin(1).$$

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin g(x)}{g(x)}=1$ is only true if $g(x)$ is continuous and if $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = 0$.  Neither of those are true for $g(x) = [x]+x$.

.....

On the intervals $[0,1)$ and $(-1,0)$ then $[x]$ is a constant value.  If $0\le x < 1$ then $[x]= 0$.  And if $-1 < x < 0$ then $[x] = -1$.

$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$ if it exists will be equal to

$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin([x]+x)}{[x]+x} = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac {\sin (0 + x)}{0 + x} =\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\sin x}x$ which be l'hopital is equal to $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\cos x}1 = 1$.

Meanwhile $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x)$ if it exists well be equal to

$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\sin([x]+x)}{[x]+x} = \lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac {\sin (-1 + x)}{-1 + x} =\frac {\sin (-1)}{-1}\ne 1$.